# React.js Ref focus()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a boolean in my component's state that I am using to decide whether an element should be in focus.

I use `React.createRef()` in the constructor and assign the ref to the `<input>` through its props. Then in render, I use an if statement to check whether the boolean is true, and call `inputRef.current.focus()` to bring it into focus if it is. The if statement is being triggered, but the element simply isn't being brought into focus.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: A minimal code example would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

you should use `this.inputRef.current.focus()`